# Google plus API is shutdown. What to do in ionic 3 app?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, google-oauth, google-plus, google-signin

I have an ionic v3 app and I have google plus login in it. I recently got a mail from google stating "Google+ API Shutdown"(refer [here](https://developers.google.com/+/api-shutdown) for more details). Google team has also said:

> 1. If you see API calls to people.get, these can be the result of using
>          the Google+ Sign-In feature in your application, which is now fully
>          deprecated and is being shut down. Developers should migrate from
>          the Google+ Sign-In feature to the more comprehensive Google Sign-in
>          authentication system.
> 2. You may see OAuth requests for plus.me, even
>          if your project is not requesting this scope directly. You only need
>          to remove such requests if your project is directly requesting this
>          scope.

I currently use`'@ionic-native/google-plus'` plugin.
 Can someone let me know what should I do with the google plus API in case of an ionic v3 project ?

Comment: Contact the owner of the project and ask them what they intend to do?

Comment: I'm the developer/owner of the app @DaImTo

Comment: What you should do will depend upon what you are doing and what you are using the google+ api for.

Comment: I'm using google API for login purpose that comes from the plugin "'@ionic-native/google-plus'"  @DalmTo

Comment: okay Will ask them @DaImTo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been told (secondhand) that although the plugin is named `google-plus`, it no longer uses the Google Plus APIs.

Comment: Oh, I see. Then Is there a way to check my app where the google plus API have used?

Comment: "This project was migrated to the non-deprecated Google Sign-In framework years ago." [source](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus/issues/555)